# ios not displaying full page and form not clickable

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm having a problem with my site which I'm doing for Freecodecamp. Everything works perfectly on desktop but it's been a nightmare on iOs. I have a few issues, but the main issues are that my last page (contact page) is not showing. iOs is cutting about 75% off from the bottom of the page, AND I can't get what little of the form that I can see to be clickable. (I've only tried this on my iPhone 7+ so far) Can anyone help please? I'll post the markup for that particular page below, but I'll also post the link to the whole site on Codepen which may help.

```
     <div id="parralax4" class="img-responsive">
     <div class="container">
     <div class="row formtitle">
     <div class="col-sm-3">
     <h2 class="formtitle1 raleway">Contact Us</h2>
     <p class="raleway">Please use the contact form...
     </div>
     <form id="xform">
     <div class="row">
     <div class="form-group col-sm-4">

     <label for="name"></label>
     <input type="name" class="form-control" id="name" 
      required placeholder="Enter name">
     </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
     <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
     <label for="email"></label>
     <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" 
     required placeholder="Enter email">
     </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
     <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
     <label for="Message"></label>
     <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="message" 
     required placeholder="Your message"></textarea>
     </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-2">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-md btn-success">Submit</button>
     </form>
     </div>
     </div>
```

[My CodePen](https://codepen.io/born_of_fire/pen/BdjPGM)

Any help greatly appreciated. I've been at this for hours trying to sort this.

Comment: Bootstrap 4 now uses img-fluid not img-responsive

Comment: Thanks. I'll change that, but I'm pretty sure that's not the issue.

Comment: you're also linking to BS 3.3.7 in th css, then you don't have the BS4 JS, Popper, and jQuery added in there.  go to https://getbootstrap.com/ gives you the links under get started section

Comment: I was originally only linking to BS 3.3.7. I tried BS 4 instead there, but it messed things up even more. I don't know what Popper is. Pretty new to this.

Comment: Popper is what BS4 uses for it .js name. I've made a few pages with BS 4 and so far so good. read this on what is popper.js https://github.com/FezVrasta/popper.js  Is all the css you have on the codepen page link? It's sort of hard for me to figure out.

Comment: Yeah, it's all there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this sorted. After a process of elimination, I hosted the site directly outside of Codepen, and it showed perfectly in Ios. So it was an issued within Codepen along with iOs.